# Ruby method expecting wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I found some strange behaviour with a method I wrote in Ruby. When I call the method with two arguments the console says that it was expecting `0..1` but when I pass one argument it says it's expecting two. Can anyone explain to me why?

```
class Friendship < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"

    def self.request(user,friend)
        unless user == friend or Friendship.exists?(user,friend)
            transaction do
                create(:user => user, :friend => friend, :status => 'pending')
                create(:user => friend, :friend => user, :status => 'requested')
            end
        end
    end

    def self.accept(user,friend)
        transaction do
            accepted_at = Time.now
            accept_one_side(user,friend,accepted_at)
            accept_one_side(friend,user,accepted_at)
        end
    end

    def self.accept_one_side(user,friend,accepted_at)
        request = find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user,friend)
        request.status = 'accepted'
        request.accepted_at = accepted_at
        request.save!
    end
end
```

It is the request method I am calling in the console like so:

```
Friendship.request(user1,user2)
```

where `user1` and `user2` are the first and second users in my database.

Comment: Add more infos to the question... what method exactly are you calling, how are you calling then on console and what are the outputs?

Comment: I have a feeling that the first error is for a method inside your method and then the second error is when calling your method.

Comment: When you call *what* method? How are you calling it? What is the exact stack trace?

Comment: Sorry I wasnt very clear there i hae updated the question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `Friendship.exists?(user,friend)` that raises the error. [`exists?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F) is a finder method that takes only one argument.

Instead you will need to write something like this:

```
Friendship.exists?(user_id: user.id, friend_id: friend.id)
```